# ¿Cómo evitar que se fusione de mala forma el repositorio de Github en Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, github

Saludos, mi problema es que en un proyecto de C# (Ya creado y colocado en github correctamente), un integrante crea un formulario "Hijo" y otro integrante del equipo crea un formulario "Hermano", el primer integrante hace un commit, pero en el segundo hace un pull pero encuentra conflictos, se hace una fusion y solo se queda con "Hijo" y a "Hermano" lo ignora por completo, porque borra el contenido, lo sobre pone y da un error de compilación. Es ahi la pregunta ¿Cómo puedo evitar que borre a "Hermano"?, que se mantengan los dos formularios como debe ser...

Comment: Tu sospechas que eso podría ser un error en la integración de git en visual studio?

Comment: No, el problema es que si agrego un boton "button1" en Hijo (desde un equipo) y otro boton "button2" (desde otro computador) igual en el formulario "Hijo", el primero lo sube sin problemas pero en el segundo equipo no deja hacer el pull porque tiene un conflicto, al fusionar no detecta los eventos "Click" de cada boton y quiere solo dejar un evento. ¿Me entienden?

Comment: Eso suena si puedes reconstruir el error. ¿sería posible que compartes el código antes y después de edición y fusión (a decir código editado de computador 1, lo mismo de 2 y el resultado fe git)?

Answer (score 1):

Sí ambos desarrolladores están trabajando en la misma rama, ahí está el problema. Estos conflictos se pueden resolver si cada desarrollador realiza sus cambios en ramas separadas. Cuando los cambios de cada rama estén terminados, estos deben mezclarse con la rama principal. Integrar los cambios con la rama principal puede hacerse de dos maneras, a través de un *merge* o un *rebase*. Te dejo este link para que determines cual es que te conviene. [Merge vs Rebase](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing).